# Reset Button Text to original Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops, button

I have buttons that text's are changed, at one point I need a group of them to change back to their original text.

I can do it manually, and set each `button.text=originalText"` but is there anyway to do this quicker?

Is there anyway to get the original text from properties and loop through to change the text? 
(they all have the same tag)

Comment: I don't think any original property is saved anywhere, so they are basically lost after you reassign them. You should save that string somewhere else in the `Button`, like in its `Tag` property, for example, so you can later loop through the buttons and do `button.Text = button.Tag`.

Comment: I would suggest you store all of your strings inside the resource file. If you need to get the original string, you could get it from the resource file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after the call to `InitializeComponent` you could create a dictionary of Buttons and their original Text property.

Suppose that you have three buttons named `Button1, Button2, Button3`

```
Dim  _originalTexts As Dictionary(Of Button, string)
Public Sub New() 
    InitializeComponents()
    _originalTexts = new Dictionary(Of Button, string)() From  _
    { _
       {Button1, Button1.Text}, _
       {Button2, Button2.Text}, _
       {Button3, Button3.Text} _
    }
End Sub
```

when you need to restore the original texts you could write

```
for each pair as KeyValuePair(Of Button, string) in _originalTexts
    pair.Key.Text = pair.Value
Next
```

Of course, having a Dictionary available in this way allows also to search a specific button.
Here an example where you search a button whose Tag property is set to something

```
Dim b = tt.Where(Function (x) x.Key.Tag.ToString = "b1").SingleOrDefault()
if b.Key IsNot Nothing Then 
    Console.WriteLine(b.Value)
End If
```

**Note:** If you don't see the `InitializeComponent` call in your form class, just type the constructor

**Public Sub New()** <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

and the IDE will reveal the missing code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable to store the default text of each button

```
Private DefaultButtonTexts as Dictionary(Of string, string)
```

After `InitializeComponent()`, store the name and text of each button into the dictionary

```
'Sub Main
    'dim form = new Form()
    'form.Controls.Add(new TextBox() With { .Name = "txt1" })
    'form.Controls.Add(new Button() With  { .Name = "btn1", .Text = "Button 1" })
    'form.Controls.Add(new Button() With  { .Name = "btn2", .Text = "Button 2" })

    'DefaultButtonTexts = form.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
     DefaultButtonTexts = this.Controls.Cast(Of Control) _
        .OfType(Of Button) _
        .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Name, Function(x) x.Text)

    'DefaultButtonTexts.Dump()

    'form.ShowDialog()
'End Sub
```

And, just restore it from the dictionary when needed

```
Private Sub RestoreText(button as Button)
    button.Text = DefaultButtonTexts(button.name)
End Sub
```

Or, restore some buttons based on the `Tag` property

```
this.Controls.Cast(Of Control) _
    .OfType(Of Button) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Tag = "tag1") _
    .ToList() _
    .ForEach(Function(x) x.Text = DefaultButtonTexts(x.name))
```